# Unit testing in Loopback with Mocha, Sinon and Chai

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai, loopback

I'm trying to get into unit testing on of my custom methods in Loopback.
The method itself clears all of the user data give parameter.

```
module.exports = function(User) {
  User.clearData = async function(options) {
    const cityId = options.accessToken.cityId;

    const deleteUserData = () => {
      return User.destroyAll({cityId: cityId}, options).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error deleting user', error);
        throw error;
      });
    };

    await deleteUserData();
  };
};
```

What I've done before is something like this :

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const {expect} = require('chai');

const clearDataUser = require('../clear-data');

describe('User clear data', ()=>{
  let spy,
    User;

  const options = {
    accessToken: {
      cityId: 1,
    },
  };

  beforeEach(()=>{
    spy = sinon.spy();
    User = {
      destroyAll: spy,
    };
  });

  it('should call destroyAll', () => {
    clearDataUser(User);
    User.destroyAll({cityId: options.accessToken.cityId}, options);
    expect(spy.callCount).to.eq(1);
  });
});
```

This will test only that `destroyAll` is called. Is there a way to test out the `catch` condition? I'm also using `async/await`, so can this also be factored in?
_____________________________________EDIT_____________________________________

I changed it up a little bit to look like :

```
  it('should call destroyAll', async() => {
    clearDataUser(User);
    const deleteUserData = () => {
      return User.destroyAll({cityId: options.accessToken.cityId}, options);
    };

    await deleteUserData();
    expect(spy.callCount).to.eq(1);
  });
```

However if I try to add `.catch(error => { expect(error).to.not.equal('undefined'); });`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

When reading the code, I found some areas that can be improved. For the source code, we can remove `deleteUserData` function. Also, what is your intention to mutate `User` object by adding `User.clearData`?

This is the improvement that I made.

```
// clear-data.js

module.exports = function(User) {
  const clearData = function(options) { // no need `async`
    const cityId = options.accessToken.cityId;

    // just return User.destroyAll directly
    return User.destroyAll({cityId: cityId}, options).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error deleting user', error);
      throw error;
    });
  };

  return {
    clearData // this is the function that we should test 
  }
};
```

And for test, I'm not sure why we test `User.destroyAll` since I expect that we test the `clearData` function here. We have to stub `User.destroyAll` to resolve promise or reject it (so catch will be executed).

Sinon has `resolves` and `rejects` method that we can use. Ref: https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const {expect} = require('chai');

const src = require('../clear-data');

describe('User clear data', () => {
  let stubDestroyAll,
      User;

  const options = {
    accessToken: {
      cityId: 1,
    },
  };

  beforeEach(()=>{
    stubDestroyAll = sinon.stub(); // mock this so we can resolve or reject the method 
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it('should call destroyAll', async () => {
    User = {
      destroyAll: stubDestroyAll.resolves(), 
    };
    const func = src(User);    
    await func.clearData(options);
    expect(stubDestroyAll.callCount).to.eq(1);
  });

  it('should catch error', async () => {
    User = {
      destroyAll: stubDestroyAll.rejects(), // reject so it will go to catch
    };
    const func = src(User);

    try {
      await func.clearData(options);            
      expect(true).to.be(false); // extra guard if it doesn't go to catch, the test will fail
    } catch(err) {
      expect(stubDestroyAll.callCount).to.eq(1);      
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.